# Keybinding conflict between VS 2017 Preview and Stable

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2019

I have VS 2017 stable and preview installed side by side. Resharper is configured only for the preview and not for the stable. However this causes issues with keybindings applied in preview for resharper shortcuts not mapping correctly on stable.

e.g. I have mapped ctrl+T for Resharper goto in VS preview. I expected that stable will have ctrl+T pointing to VS default Goto All since resharper is not configured but apparently not the case.

Is there a way to keep the key bindings independent between preview and stable ?

Comment: Similar conflicts between VS 2019 preview and VS 2017, guess there is no way around this ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by unchecking the synchronize settings across devices in VS settings. Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts -> Synchronize settings across devices when signed into Visual Studio